# Vector inequation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

$${A_i} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{{A_{i1}}}\\{{A_{i2}}}\\ \vdots \\{{A_{in}}}\end{array}} \right),{B_i} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{{B_{i1}}}\\{{B_{i2}}}\\ \vdots \\{{B_{in}}}\end{array}} \right).{B_{ij}},{A_{ij}} \in R
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHbl7mZLdGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqr
% pepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs
% 0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaai
% aabeqaamaabaabauaakeaacaWGbbWaaSbaaSqaaiaadMgaaeqaaOGa
% eyypa0ZaaeWaaeaafaqabeabbaaaaeaacaWGbbWaaSbaaSqaaiaadM
% gacaaIXaaabeaaaOqaaiaadgeadaWgaaWcbaGaamyAaiaaikdaaeqa
% aaGcbaGaeSO7I0eabaGaamyqamaaBaaaleaacaWGPbGaamOBaaqaba
% aaaaGccaGLOaGaayzkaaGaaiilaiaadkeadaWgaaWcbaGaamyAaaqa
% baGccqGH9aqpdaqadaqaauaabeqaeeaaaaqaaiaadkeadaWgaaWcba
% GaamyAaiaaigdaaeqaaaGcbaGaamOqamaaBaaaleaacaWGPbGaaGOm
% aaqabaaakeaacqWIUlstaeaacaWGcbWaaSbaaSqaaiaadMgacaWGUb
% aabeaaaaaakiaawIcacaGLPaaacaGGUaGaamOqamaaBaaaleaacaWG
% PbGaamOAaaqabaGccaGGSaGaamyqamaaBaaaleaacaWGPbGaamOAaa
% qabaGccqGHiiIZcaWGsbaaaa!6685!
$$
prove
$$\sum\limits_{1 \le i,j \le n} {\left| {{A_i} - {B_j}} \right|}  \ge \sum\limits_{1 \le i < j \le n} {\left( {\left| {{A_i} - {A_j}} \right| + \left| {{B_i} - {B_j}} \right|} \right)} 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHbl7mZLdGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqr
% pepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs
% 0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaai
% aabeqaamaabaabauaakeaadaaeqbqaamaaemaabaGaamyqamaaBaaa
% leaacaWGPbaabeaakiabgkHiTiaadkeadaWgaaWcbaGaamOAaaqaba
% aakiaawEa7caGLiWoaaSqaaiaaigdacqGHKjYOcaWGPbGaaiilaiaa
% dQgacqGHKjYOcaWGUbaabeqdcqGHris5aOGaeyyzIm7aaabuaeaada
% qadaqaamaaemaabaGaamyqamaaBaaaleaacaWGPbaabeaakiabgkHi
% TiaadgeadaWgaaWcbaGaamOAaaqabaaakiaawEa7caGLiWoacqGHRa
% WkdaabdaqaaiaadkeadaWgaaWcbaGaamyAaaqabaGccqGHsislcaWG
% cbWaaSbaaSqaaiaadQgaaeqaaaGccaGLhWUaayjcSdaacaGLOaGaay
% zkaaaaleaacaaIXaGaeyizImQaamyAaiabgYda8iaadQgacqGHKjYO
% caWGUbaabeqdcqGHris5aaaa!6EEF!
$$
with equality only in
$$\left\{ {{A_i}} \right\} = \left\{ {{B_i}} \right\}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHbl7mZLdGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqr
% pepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs
% 0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaai
% aabeqaamaabaabauaakabaaaaaaaaapeqaa8aadaGadaqaaiaadgea
% daWgaaWcbaGaamyAaaqabaaakiaawUhacaGL9baacqGH9aqpdaGada
% qaaiaadkeadaWgaaWcbaGaamyAaaqabaaakiaawUhacaGL9baaaaa!488D!
$$
I encountered this problem while doing an engineering research.
I did lots of tests using computer program, and the inequality stands.
To prove it, I have tried the triangle inequality, mathematical induction and anything else that I can think of, and I failed.
In the triangle inequality, The number of the items in one side is twice as the other side. However, there are n^2 items in LHS and n*(n-1) items in RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Consider proving the sufficiency. Start with $A = B$, and then you get that the right hand side is exactly the left hand side (not that $i = j$ and $A = B$ implies $A_i - B_j = 0$), as you mentioned because the sum is over *all* $1 \le i,j \le n$, *not* requiring $i < j$. Hence the claim holds this way around.

To do the other way around, assume that the inequality holds and do some manipulation. I recommend using the triangle inequality,

$$ |x + y| \le |x| + |y|,$$

but also from this you can obtain another triangle inequality that is

$$ |x - y| \ge | |x| - |y| |.$$

Manipulating this should help.

---

Hopefully this answer is of assistance! If so, please remember to upvote! =D

All the best, Sam.

Comment: I think $LHS=RHS$ when $A=B$. There is both $|A_1 - B_2|$ and $|A_2 - B_1|$ in $LHS$, which are equal to $(|A_1 - A_2| + |B_1 - B_2|)$ in $RHS$. It's $1 \le i,j \le n$ in $LHS$ and $1 \le i<j \le n$ in $RHS$.

Comment: Ah, apologies; you are correct. I noticed that, but because the other side was different, I thought that it was a typo... then forgot to mention it! I'll update my answer. The principle for the second part still holds, however.

Comment: I tried  the triangle inequality, and I failed, then I found it's impossible to prove it using  the triangle inequality.In the triangle inequality, The number of the items in one side is twice as the other side. However, there are n^2 items in LHS and n*(n-1) items in RHS.

Comment: You may find that if you start from something like
$$ \sum_{1 \le i < j < n} \text{something} $$
then you can use the triangle inequality to get up to $n(n+1)$ terms, but then have $n$ of them cancel. I'm not sure exactly though. Sorry to not be of more help!